# Remove sub-array within a numpy array if any item in it has already appeared in a previous array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, duplicates, vectorization

I have an two-dimensional numpy array. I need to filter out duplications - if any item in a row is there in a previous row, then it's considered a duplication.

```
#i.e.:
arr =
array([[4580, 4581, 4657, 4658],
       [4580, 4581, 4657, 4659], #-> duplicate because of 4580
       [4650, 4652, 4654, 4655],
       [4651, 4655, 4652, 4656]]) #-> duplicate because of 4652

#Output should be: 
array([[4580, 4581, 4657, 4658],
       [4650, 4652, 4654, 4655]])
```

The below script gives me my expected output for small inputs. It chokes on large arrays, however. I'm sure there's a much simpler and more efficient way to do this but I can't seem to find it.

```
check = np.array([not(np.in1d(a, np.unique(arr[:i])).any()) for i,a in enumerate(arr)])
arr[check]
```

Comment: Is it possible for a single row to contain duplicates?

Comment: " have an array of numpy arrays" no, no you do not.

Answer (score 2):

You can find unique elements of the array using [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html). Passing the argument `return_index=True` returns the indices of the first occurrence of the unique elements. Note that since `unique` implicitly flattens the array, these values are indices in the *flattened* array.

```
unique_elems, unique_indices = np.unique(arr, return_index=True)
# array([4580, 4581, 4650, 4651, 4652, 4654, 4655, 4656, 4657, 4658, 4659]),
# array([ 0,  1,  8, 12,  9, 10, 11, 15,  2,  3,  7], dtype=int64)
```

Now, we want to select any rows, where *all* its elements are in the `unique_indices` array. First, let's create an array which maps the index of an element in the flattened array to its position in `arr`:

```
mapping = np.arange(arr.size).reshape(arr.shape)
```

Now, let's see which indices are in `unique_indices`:

```
select_elem = np.isin(mapping, unique_indices)
# array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
#        [False, False, False,  True],
#        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
#        [ True, False, False,  True]])
```

And finally, select only the rows of `select_elem` which are all `True`:

```
select_rows = select_elem.all(axis=1)
# array([ True, False,  True, False])
```

Using this to index into the array, we get the desired result:

```
result = arr[select_rows]
# array([[4580, 4581, 4657, 4658],
#        [4650, 4652, 4654, 4655]])
```

Here's how the performance varies with input size:

[image]

[Timeless's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76047464/843953) method is (unsurprisingly) nearly identical to yours, since it has the same bottleneck, an iteration in python over the array. The pure-numpy approach I showed above runs significantly faster. I did not time [Yossi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76047513/843953) method because it gives the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that aligns with yours :

```
out = np.concatenate([arr[i:i+1] for i, a in enumerate(arr)
                      if not np.isin(a, np.unique(arr[:i])).any()], axis=0)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

[[4580 4581 4657 4658]
 [4650 4652 4654 4655]]
```

Comment: For a slightly bigger `(15, 10)` array, this is about as fast (slightly slower) than OP's approach

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[4580, 4581, 4657, 4658],
       [4580, 4581, 4657, 4659], #-> duplicate because of 4580
       [4650, 4652, 4654, 4655],
       [4651, 4655, 4652, 4656]]) #-> duplicate because of 4652

tot_mask = np.zeros_like(arr)
tmp_mask = np.zeros_like(arr)
arr_shifted = arr
for ii, cur_col in enumerate(range(arr.shape[0]-2)):
    arr_shifted = np.roll(arr_shifted,-1, axis=0)[:-1,:]
    for cur_col in range(arr.shape[1]):
        mask = arr[:-(ii+1),:] == arr_shifted
        tmp_mask[ii+1:,:] = mask
        tot_mask = np.logical_or(tot_mask, tmp_mask)
        tmp_mask = np.zeros_like(arr)
        arr_shifted = np.roll(arr_shifted,-1, axis=1)
any_eq = np.logical_not(np.any(tot_mask, 1))

return arr[any_eq,:]
```

output:

```
[[4580 4581 4657 4658]
 [4650 4652 4654 4655]]
```

---

EDITED: due to pranav comment.
The idea is to roll all rows one row up, and iterate over rolls in columns dimension. If any of the numbers is identical to one of the numbers in upper row the row is ommited.

Fixed the implementation to check over all previous rows.

Comment: In addition to a lack of explanation, this fails on some inputs. See [this example](https://www.online-python.com/9GYAaenW0F) -- your method just returns the original

Comment: Thanks for your comment. First, I edited my comment to conclude an explanation for the implementation. Second, I think that we understood Kristof differently. As I understand him, filter out a row if one of it's element exist in the previous row only, as I understand your example you filter out a row if one of its elements is in one of the previous rows.

Comment: I agree that OP's example doesn't distinguish those two possibilities, but since they say _"if any item in an array is there in **a** previous array"_ instead of **the** previous array, I'm inclined to think my interpretation is what they're looking for

Comment: Agree, fixed my implementation. Now it is much slower actually